# Paragraph inline with img

Tags: html, css, alignment, inline

I am having a problem aligning a paragraph with an image inline.

```
<p id="intro">blah blah blah lots of text.</p>
<img src="macro.jpg" height="476" id="photograph" width="267" />
```

I've tried in CSS this:

```
  #intro {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    }

  #photograph {
    float: right;
    }
```

But it still doesn't align them... Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to make it fluid when you resize the window.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbyhsfmu/)

```
#photograph {
    float: right;
    width: 267px;

}
#intro {    
  width: calc(100% - 267px);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is ti something like this you looking for???

```css
#intro {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: black;
  
    }

  #photograph {
   
    }
    .test{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      background-color:pink;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p id="intro">blah blah blah lots of text.</p>
<img src="macro.jpg" height="476" id="photograph" width="267" />
</div>
```